# Creating a subsite from Site Definition gives access denied in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-definition

i have a Site Definition that creates discussion board, blog, and wiki, when creating the sub site based on this definition it behaves as the following:

1- if i'm logged in as System Account, the sub site creation works fine

2- if i'm logged in as any user who have Full Control, the sub site creation using inherited permissions works fine

3- if i'm logged in as any user who have Full Control, the sub site creation using special  permissions option it gives access denied.

i tried the following:

1- checked in/published all page layouts and master pages, but never works

2- checked any provisioned feature, web part, nothing strange, even when debugging

3- tried to uncheck/recheck the Create Groups under CA -> User Permissions for Web Application, also never works

4- Checked that the user (who has full control) is added to readers in Style Library permissions

any help is appreciated.

Note: here's the Log entry when searching for 'Access Denied':

> Could not retrieve a valid windows identity for username 'domain\account' with UPN 'account@domain'. UPN is required when Kerberos constrained delegation is used

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with breaking permission inheritance on the subsite with special permissions.

Try running the whole code that creates sites under elevated permissions with Security.RunWithElevatedPrivileges.

Comment: i double checked the custom code, everything uses RunWithElevatedPrivilige properly

Comment: A new SPWeb object is created within the elevated context using the elevated SPSite object?

Comment: yes, i'm creating both SPSite and SPWeb using ElevatedPriviliges

Answer (score 0):

Check the user has access to Sql Database, if the user does not have access to Sql databse on Sharepoint config database, you cannot create subsite.